# What does Get do in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to modify a program someone wrote in VB6 in the sem-distant past, and have come across the line below, and many similar ones. My question is, syntactically, what does this "Get" line look like it does or might do?

```
  Get #3, StartByte + Offset, StudentScrBytes
```

Within the program, it's ALWAYS followed by 3 comma-separated items, and with one exception, the first item is a number preceded by #. The second looks to always resolve to a number, and the third a single variable.

I'm fairly sure I've figured out the numbers preceded by # are a file reference - the first time Get appears, instead of #3 or #10 or #whatever, it has a variable "TempFile" instead, initialized as [FreeFile().](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3zyf7d8(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
  TempFile = FreeFile()
  Open "c:\folerName.dir" For Binary Shared As TempFile
```

The only stuff I've been able to find on Get in VB6, seems to relate to OOP and getters/setters. Maybe I'm wrong, but I really don't think that's what's going on here, and all I have are vague guesses as to what is.

Here's the function the line was taken from. Both arguments are integers.

```
Function StudentScr$(Record, Contest)

  Dim StudentScrBytes As String * 4
  StartByte = (Record - 1) * LengthOfStudentRecord
  If Contest = 1 Then Offset = 77
  If Contest = 2 Then Offset = 85
  If Contest = 3 Then Offset = 94
  If Contest = 4 Then Offset = 102
  If Contest = 5 Then Offset = 110
  If Contest = 6 Then Offset = 118
  If Contest = 7 Then Offset = 126
  If Contest = 8 Then Offset = 134
  Get #3, StartByte + Offset, StudentScrBytes
  StudentScr$ = StudentScrBytes

End Function
```

I would think Get would get something from the specified file, except I can't tell how (or if) a file is even specified at all.

Comment: Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278468.aspx (VBA, but identical to VB6)

Comment: I would like to know how you found this. Even now, I can't find it via Google, trying 3 different search strings!

Comment: I know the VB6 documentation has been taken down so I searched for `office vba get keyword` because I forgot what `get` was (an operator? a clause?). That led to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264285.aspx which led to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278468.aspx.

Comment: @Herb I'm only seeing VBA and Visual Studio 6.0

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the cursor on the word and press F1?

Comment: @Noodles, it tells me "MSDN collection doesn't exist. Please reinstall MSDN", and that seems like a headache in itself, to me

Comment: @ whoever downvoted, WHY? I'm assuming it wasn't Noodles, since it was downvoted today, not yesterday

Comment: It wasn't me. When you install VS6 it will offer to install the help files which it calls MSDN.

Comment: I googled "vb6 get" and the very first link (http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/reading-and-writing-binary-files-visual-basic) explains all the basics.

Comment: The #3 must refer to a file number used (hardcoded as well) elsewhere in the program where some file was opened.

Comment: FYI The VB6 documentation is still on MSDN online, here's the [overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130517.aspx), the [reference guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032(v=vs.60).aspx) is excellent, the "Getting started with..." and "Using ..." are excellent introductions to the language and platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the original MS VB6 documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243376(v=vs.60).aspx

You may also be interested in its counterpart Put:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266212(v=vs.60).aspx

Hint: when searching for legacy VB statements, include "vs.60" for Visual Studio 6.0 in your Google search, and restrict your search to the MS site. MS hast this term in the official link, so you can not miss it. This search:

vb6 vs.60 get put site:microsoft.com

does bring up both Get and Put as the two first Google answers on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

With a VB6 binary file, `Get` is simple. You seek to a **specific** point in the data in the file and then you **get** (n) bytes.

It's similar to the QuickBasic Random Access File, but because it is **shared**, the VB6 binary file lets lots of apps to contemporaneously cherry pick data. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I use Binary Shared all the time. Precise changes in a SHARED file where data is being accessed. Perfect for giving instructions and the other program reading them. In another way of explaining, it is "cherry picking" data from a precise position in a file. The beauty is that apart from error trapping, there's no need to create the file over and over and create error in the process.

It should be available in every language.

Back in the day, MS MASM did it. And QuickBasic. The nomenclature was different, but the process exactly the same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).